# How to get list of all named system events ? (from EventWaitHandler Global\)

Tags: c#

I am can create system wide semaphore as

```
new EventWaitHandle(... @"Global\OurCompany.OurProduct.MyClass.EventWaitHandle" ...);
```

How can i am get list of all such events from another application ?

I am want register some switch with my application and make console utility, what can manipulate them outside runtime.

Comment: Honestly, now you made me curious. I know Process Monitor does it, it can display all those handles in the lower window. I looked all over the MSDN and I could not find any method that enumerates the created handles.